# Object Managment - Container or Factory?

Tags: c++, oop, factory-pattern

I'm nearing the end of a introductory game programming class, and would like to combine the skills I learned in class with my previous OOP experience to create a small library for making 2D games.  My current concern, though, it the best way to manage collections of instances of my classes.

The library I'm using (DarkGDK) is made up entirely of free functions that act on integers.  When an "object" is created with a function such as dbSprite(), you give it a unique ID (`int` value) to refer to it with--an "address" of sorts, I guess.  I personally find this approach apalling, so I've created classes to encapsulate each set of free functions such as Image, Sprite, and AnimatedSprite (the two sprite types are different in the DarkGDK library.)

The trouble is, in order for these objects to work, I still have to pass a unique ID to the constructor in order to call the DarkGDK functions against the appropriate address.  I'm trying to move away from refering to these things by ID all together, but I'm debating on how the objects should be created.  At the moment I have some AssetManager classes that holds references to each object created, check for existing IDs and only allow unique ones, but this still does not solve the problem of being forced to generate an ID external to the management class.  This led me to think a Factory would be the best approach.

I know in C# I could create an `AssetFactory<T> where T:Asset` that can easily call the appropriate constructors for each Asset to create the instances, but to my knowledge C++ has no such facilites.

So I think the approach I should take is using some sort of abstract AssetFactory.  *My* idea (correct or not) is that children of the AssetFactory would keep track of the IDs in use and only issue approriate objects unique IDs.  Something like this:

```
class Asset {
    int m_index;
    Asset(int index);
};
class Image : public Asset {
    Image(char* imgPath);
    void Draw();
};
class Sprite : public Asset {
    Sprite(Image* img);
    void Draw();
};

class AssetFactory {
private:
    std::vector<Asset*> m_assets;
    int GetUniqueID();
public:
    AssetFactory();
    ~AssetFactory();

    virtual Asset* CreateAsset(); // but each class has different constructor parameters...
};

class ImageFactory : public AssetFactory {
    Asset* CreateAsset(char* imgPath); // ...so this wouldn't work (nor compile)
};
class SpriteFactory : public AssetFactory {
    Asset* CreateAsset();   // ...so will i be forced to call the default constructor and modify it later?
};
```

The problem here is that, as noted above, the different objects have different constructors, making this design moot.  Should I be taking a different approach?  Or do I just have the wrong idea of the Factory Pattern?

**EDIT:** For clarification, the reason I want separate factories for Sprites and Images is because it *is* admissable for a Sprite and an image to have the same ID.  The IDs must only be unique among other assets of the same "type."

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, but I'm voting it back to a zero.

Comment: FYI: The integer method is generally called a Handle, since you're not interfacing with the data structure directly by pointer, but by a handle (the integer) to it.

Comment: @Daemin:  That's the term I was looking for.  Thank you.  Is this common practice in C?  Even though the library was release with MVC2008, it's pitched as a C++ library, though it's architecture and behavior seems very C-like to me.

Comment: It is used in OpenGL, and with different typedefs in the Win32 API (usually with HANDLE and H prefixed types HINSTANCE, HICON, etc).

Comment: Wow.  Shows how much I know.  I though the whole HANDLE (hWnd and such) pratice in the Windows API were just typedefs for actual pointers.

Comment: In some cases they are pointers into memory, but not in the application's memory space. For instance in Windows CE the drivers return opaque HANDLE values which can (but not necessarily do) translate directly to memory locations in the kernel's/driver's memory space.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty trivial problem to solve, if your library allows arbitrary IDs and you're working in a relatively equal address space (e.g. sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)), which is true on virtually all 32bit compilers that I know of. Generating the IDs is then trivial- just reinterpret_cast the pointer.

```
class Sprite {
    int GetUniqueID() { return reinterpret_cast<int>(this); } // easies
public:
    // public interface
};
```

In addition, it's actually probably not worth it to re-use old IDs. Just keep making new ones. I mean, you're not gonna run out of space in a 32bit integer.

Finally, you definitely cannot use run-time inheritance here. Use a compile-time mixin, if you must.

Comment: That's a great idea! Unfortunately, the max value for an ID is USHRT_MAX, so I'll have to do some extra manipulating to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Use reinterpret_cast sparingly.  When you use it, you are essentially telling the compiler "Hey stupid, shut up.  I know EXACTLY what I'm doing."

Answer (score 0):

Where C# has generics, C++ has templates.  You can't so easily provide the constraints on the generic parameter in C++, but there are ways to make sure that you only give a derived-from-Asset type as the template parameter.

In order to pass the appropriate parameters to the constructor, you can use a variadic template method.  I don't have a compiler available to me at the moment... I'll edit again later with an example, although you can find plenty of other variadic template code on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm aware of the template capability available to me, but the issue is not so much ensuring the object created is of Asset type, but rather how to call the appropriate objects constructor *with it's associated parameters*.

Comment: @wtfsven: Edited my answer to mention variadic templates.

Comment: C++03 does not support variadic templates, so I'm out of luck there.

Comment: @wtfsven: That's too bad.  Any chance you could upgrade?  GCC and Clang both have a good amount of variadic support already.

Comment: @Micheal Price:  Not in this case.  It's for a class that requires the use of MVC2008.  (This particular aspect of the program is WAY beyond the scope of the class; I'm just trying to go above and beyond.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed something, it wasn't clear for me you why couldn't move the ID generator inside the AssetManager, this way hiding all the misery of the unique IDs from the outside world.

Anyway, if you need to keep track of the IDs you will need the manager class as far as I can tell at this point from your post. If you use factory methods instead of factory classes you have just arrived to the finish line :) The only problem which remains is the disposal of the IDs, but you can do in the virtual destructor of the Asset class. If you want to keep it clean, then you should provide a protected method for it in the manager, and make the Asset classes destructor (or some Cleanup function) friend of the manager.

Comment: I've actually changed my architecture around to enable this approach.  Now I'm just playing around with the Factory Pattern.  :)  Thanks for the input.